# How to get the return value of a function type that inherits a basic type interface

Tags: typescript, return-type, conditional-types

Usually, we can use built-in utility types `ReturnType` to retrieve the return value of function type, like this:

```ts
interface A {
  (...args: any): string
}

type Return = ReturnType<A> // Return will be 'string'
```

Now, we use a new type B to inherit A

```ts
interface A {
  (...args: any): any
}

interface B extends A {
  (config: Record<string, string>): Promise<void>
}

type Return = ReturnType<B> // Return will be 'any' instead of 'Promise<void>'
```

The return value doesn't meet my expectations, and I can't figure out the return type of B in any way.

I tried to implement a tool similar to `ReturnType` like that:

```ts
type ReturnPromisedType<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: any) => Promise<infer R> ? R : never;
```

Type `A` is always compatible with conditional types, and `any` is used to match `Promise <infer P>` to infer that `P` is `unknown`

Comment: Are you just trying to get the `ReturnType` when you pass one parameter to the function?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just sawed the previous opinion of the union type, but I didn't understand what this comment means, how to pass one parameter when dealing with types

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at the definition of `ReturnType` you'll find your answer:

```js
type ReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => any> =
    T extends (...args: any) => infer R ? R : any;
```

Typescript infers your return type of the interface (i.e. `R = any`) and thus returns any for `A`. For the extension with `B extends A` Patrick Roberts explained the union in the comments.

Comment: The union type that Patrick Roberts mentioned did give me a new idea, but how can I obtain the return value of B (Promise<void>)?

Comment: @liangzr Since both signatures get merged into a more generic one (since their virtually the same) I can only propose to not extend from `A` since you can always type-assert any `B` to be an `A`.

Comment: lvicevic Thanks for your suggestion. Although the type `A` and the arrow function are identical in structure, I still want to use A to specify one of my generic parameters. Perhaps I don’t need to let B to inherit A here because B and A are also compatible in structure